# php trait using another trait

Tags: php, class, oop, traits

I have a trait that is using another trait, and now I'm getting errors about functions that don't exist in classes.

I have simplified the code:

##### `settings.php`

```php
<?php

trait settings {
    // read setting from config.ini
    protected function getSetting($type, $setting){
        try {
            $configFile = dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.ini";
            if (!file_exists($configFile) || !is_file($configFile))
                throw new Exception("Config file was not found. ");

            $configContents = parse_ini_file($configFile,true);
            if (is_array($configContents) && array_key_exists($type, $configContents) && is_array($configContents[$type]) && array_key_exists($setting, $configContents[$type]))
                return $configContents[$type][$setting];
            else
                throw new Exception("Setting ".$setting." could not be found in ".$type.".");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

##### `database.php`

```php
<?php
trait database {
    use settings, session;

    private $pdo;

    // connect to database
    protected function connect() {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=".$this->getSetting("db", "host").";dbname=".$this->getSetting("db", "database"),
                $this->getSetting("db", "user"),
                $this->getSetting("db","password")
            );

            $this->init();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

##### `users.php`

```php
<?php

class users {
    use database;

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->connect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        unset($this);
    }

    public function isAdmin() {
        try {
            if ($this->loginStatus() === true) {
            } else
                return false;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function loginStatus() {
        if (!$this->getSession("tysus") || !$this->getSession("tyspw"))
            // user is not logged in because we couldn't find session with username and/or password
            return false;

        if (!$this->userExists($this->getSession("tysus"), $this->getSession("tyspw")))
            // user is unknown to database
            return false;

        // other checks failed, user must be logged in
        return true;
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method users::readSetting() in /home/deb2371/domains/nonamenohistory.com/public_html/include/classes/class.database.php on line 18

What I thought would happen was something like this:
Class `users` uses `database` trait and that trait would use `settings` and `session` traits.

If that were the case, I wouldn't be getting any errors, but unfortunately, this isn't the case.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why should I not use traits? Please explain.

Comment: Because, besides making huge mess regarding violations of SOLID principles, they also are actually implemented (under the hood) as interpreter-assisted copy-paste.

Comment: I don't understand why that's the case.

Comment: Furthermore, why catch an exception just to throw a new exception with the same message?

Comment: Can you please update your question that it IS possible so we do not waste time on reading about a syntax error? ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your issue may be due to you using `readSetting` but it is actually called `getSetting`

Answer (score 44):

> *Code reuse is one of the most important aspects of object-oriented programming.*

A simple example of *Multiple Traits* and *Composing Multiple Traits* by which you can easily analyze your situation.

1. ###### Using multiple traits

A class can use multiple traits. The following example demonstrates how to use multiple traits in the IDE class.

It simulates the C compilation model in PHP for the sake of demonstration.

```php
<?php

trait Preprocessor {
    function preprocess() {
        echo 'Preprocess...done' . '<br/>';
    }
}

trait Compiler {
    function compile() {
        echo 'Compile code... done' . '<br/>';
    }
}

trait Assembler {
    function createObjCode() {
        echo 'Create the object code files... done.' . '<br/>';
    }
}

trait Linker {
    function createExec() {
        echo 'Create the executable file...done' . '<br/>';
    }
}

class IDE {
    use Preprocessor, Compiler, Assembler, Linker;

    function run() {
        $this->preprocess();
        $this->compile();
        $this->createObjCode();
        $this->createExec();

        echo 'Execute the file...done' . '<br/>';
    }
}

$ide = new IDE();
$ide->run();
```

2. **Composing multiple traits**

A trait can be composed of other traits by using the `use` statement in the trait’s declaration. See the following example:

```php
<?php

trait Reader {
    public function read($source) {
        echo sprintf("Read from %s <br/>", $source);
    }
}

trait Writer {
    public function write($destination) {
        echo sprintf("Write to %s <br/>", $destination);
    }
}

trait Copier {
    use Reader, Writer;

    public function copy($source, $destination) {
        $this->read($source);
        $this->write($destination);
    }
}

class FileUtil {
    use Copier;

    public function copyFile($source, $destination) {
        $this->copy($source, $destination);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly, considering the generic title on this question, this answer will be the correct one for 99% of visitors. Thanks for the nice detailed examples! (in my case, I only wound up here because of a "syntax error" of my own, but your examples clarified I had my traits configured right, and I found the problem, as predicted)

Comment: Is `class FileUtil { use Reader; use Copier; … }` (with `Copier` already containing `Reader`) an error, or what is happening then?

Comment: @luckydonald - Can you put down the error in your case here.

Comment: I was asking if it works. From what I've seen it actually isn't an error, and it works to include the same trait twice.